# Laravel merge result of two relationships that point to one table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an `orders_products` table. For a one-to-many relationship. One order can have multiple products. And every license is unique to an ordered product. Because every license is uniquely generated for that given product.

The `orders_products` table has an order ID and a product_id and a license_id. This is because all orders have a related product and a related license.

[image]

In the `Order` model I have these relationships:

```
class Order extends Model {

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'orders_products', 'order_id', 'product_id');
}

public function licenses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(License::class, 'orders_products', 'license_id');
}
}
```

But now I would like the licenses to show up in the product objects. Because they are related. So somehow these relationships need to be merged?

When retrieving the data:

```
$data = Order::with('products', 'licenses')->get();
```

The result is incomplete:

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1, <!-- id of the orders table
        "user_id": "2",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Product 1",
                "price": "100.0",
                "license": null <-- here I would like to licenses relation to kick in
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Product 2",
                "price": "100.0",
                "license": null
            }
        ],
        "payed_at": "2020-02-21 17:07:49",
        "payed": true
    }
]
```

}

As you can see the product data gets populated the right way. But the licenses get attached separately. But they need to be part of a product.

So how to merge the results of the columns product_id and license_id from the table `order_products` table?

**Update:**

I think the solution somehow lies in calling license() on the Product model.

```
"products": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Developer Forms Plugin",
                "price": "100.0",
                "license": {
                    "id": null,
                    "license": null,
                    "slots": null
                }
            }]
```

Is how the output should be. The license being unique to every **ordered** product. Just having a license for each product is not enough. They are generated for every ordered product.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like :

```
$data = Order::with('products.license')->get();
```

This way we can get the license related to the products. I called license because you described a one to one relation between them, so I assumed that you wrote it in singular.

Comment: I think this will result in a product having 1 license. But that's not the case. Every order of a product needs to have a unique license.

Comment: So every order has a single license and many products? The way you pointed in code example, for me, tells that you need "license": null to become the object within product-license one-to-one relationship. The code i posted does the "But now I would like the licenses to show up in the product objects. Because they are related. So somehow these relationships need to be merged?" part of your question.

Comment: In `Order::with('products.license')->get();` Order fetch all orders  and with('products.license') get all products within the order, and then get the license related to the product. If your order has 10 products, every one of those products will come to the related license and every field in it.